# Переход с Windows 10 на Linux Ubuntu - какие подводные камни?

Tags: linux, windows

Возникла ситуация когда у меня слишком много источников по данному вопросу и я до конца не могу определится. Суть в чем - сейчас у меня на ноутбуке стоит Windows 10 Pro которой я пользуюсь почти с того момента когда она только вышла. Но сейчас я задался вопросом - может стоит перейти на убунту. Я по специальности, или по сфере интересов, кому как будет удобнее - Android разработчик. Все мое это IDE эмулятор и браузер. То есть ось почти не играет роли в процессе разработки. Я на одном стороннем ПК попробовал поработать под убунтой, и честно сказать у меня не было особых проблем. То есть конечно разница есть и все прочее, но меня интересуют возможные проблемы связанные с переходом (кроме особенности ос в целом). К примеру - у меня на винде стоит офис, на убунту конечно есть либр офис, но к майкрософту ему далековато, поэтому если что буду юзать либо гугл доки либо офис 365, все остальное типа эмулятора или IDE работает так же как и на винде. Проблема винды в том что нужно ооочень много сделать чтобы все работало ровно и красиво - кучу всего нужно прописать в реестре и в других местах. Так же интересует довольно острый вопрос - что делать с драйверами, ведь из под винды все просто, скачал файл установил и все красиво, а что делать на убунте например? Что вы можете посоветовать в данной ситуации, а то у меня дилемма)) Надеюсь на ваши полезные советы :)

Comment: Поставить убунту, начать ей пользоваться. Решать проблемы по мере поступления. Лучше со сносом винды, ибо привычка - вторая натура, и вы можете начать лазить в нее. `что делать с драйверами` - с новым железом проблемы редкие, многие вендоры уже оринетируются и на GNU Linux. Могут быть проблемы со сканерами и принтерами. На видюхи есть проприетарные дрова, они качаются. Также в убунте о вас уже позаботились и при установке спросят на счет установки проприетарных кодеков (mp3 и что-то еще). Лично я перешел по похожим причинам более пяти лет и доволен.

Comment: @TotalPusher, просто я при установке вынды кучу дров поставил и сейчас есть опасения что что-то не будет работать так как нужно)) поэтому и опасаюсь сразу перескакивать с винды на линукс)

Comment: Ну грузанитесь с флешки, посмотрите что работает, что нет. Поставьте дрова с сайта вендора для видюхи. Вы ищите моральную поддержку, или технические советы. Если советы - пишите свое железо, может кто-то скажет, есть с ним проблемы или нет.

Comment: Дрова 5-ти летней давности в убунте почти все есть. На современное нужно фирмваре доустановить посвежее.

Comment: @eri, а что за фирмваре и где его брать? а то у меня есть стойкое впечатление что на винду есть все а на убунту ничего не найдешь и будут в итоге проблемы какие-то))

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko https://github.com/q3aql/drivers-linux-firmware большой драйверпак, есть всё, в том числе на видюхи последних райзенов.

Comment: @eri, и это получается вот этот один драйверпак включает в себя все драйвера или так нужно все драйвера искать, я возможно задаю глупые вопросы не спорю, просто менять ось нужно с умом))

Comment: @eri, это, простите, что за поделка? Она наводит меня на странные мысли: непонятный пакет, с какого-то непопулярного гит-репо. Лично я такое ставь боюсь.

Comment: С видюхами самый гемор. Под старые надо подбирать старые дрова. Под новые искать фирмварь. Под вайфай фирмварь есть в пакетах убунты почти на всё.

Comment: @TotalPusher человек старался по сусекам насобирал дров, а вы его боитесь) звездочек не набрал потому что почти все уже есть в убунте. Я с этим паком запускаю компы на am4 - в скриптах ничего вредного не нашел. 15 лет назад я как вы говорил про dps (драйверпаксолюшн) особенно хейтил за галочку с левым ПО. Но потом научился её снимать. Эта дебка упрощает работу, но весит дохера). На проверенном железе apt install firmware-linux firmware-realtek и красота

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko драйвер состоит из 2х частей модуль ядра и фирмварь. Тут только фирмварь. Модули ядра (кроме нвидии) уже в ядре есть

Comment: @eri, конретно тот пакетик, возможно и хороший, но вот посмотрите другими глазами: человек может быть только что увидел deb пакет, и поставил его не думая. А потом еще и еще. Рано или поздно появится не совсем хороший пакет. На первых порах, до понимания что к чему, уж лучше использовать стандартные репы.

Comment: Если говорить об Ubuntu, то я предпочитаю ее вариант с xfce дисплей менеджером (т.н. xubuntu), такой графический интерфейс мне ближе

Comment: @TotalPusher главное чтоб СБИС не поставил случайно))

Comment: Если лет 10 назад была разница, то сейчас особой разницы нет. Много чего из софта доступно в linux, а чего недоступно есть в веб. Особой разницы нет, сила привычки и всё. Ну и плюс в linux, само собой больший контроль. Может бесить Wayland (как работает), но можно на Xorg перейти и всё

Comment: Главный подводный камень при переходе — это мыслить по-виндовски. Лучшая винда — это винда, поэтому не ищите в линуксах лучшей винды. Как и лучшего MS офиса. LO — это LO, у него свой подход и свои форматы, например. И вы зря считаете, что в линуксах не надо оочень много делать, чтобы довести систему под себя. Просто там в принципе можно сделать больше в этом направлении, и часто так оно и бывает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Набор софта отличается но не так все плохо, с тем же офисом помимо онлайновых сервисов есть еще WPS Office, у него получше с совместимостью с MS форматами, насколько я помню для индивидуального использования он бесплатен,а если очень надо то можно и ms office через wine запустить,  допилка той же ubuntu после установки нужна но ничего радикального тут не требуется, с дровами тут все интереснее как правило из коробки подхватывается почти все, те же nvidia ставятся в пару щелчков мышки, железо  от intel и amd обычно работает из коробки, принтеры если не полный хлам, как правило тоже подхватываются автоматически включая сетевые, если все равно сильно сомневавшийся стоит ли, то просто поставь систему на виртуальную машину.

Comment: а как под nvidia пару щелчков, что искать нужно будет?)

Comment: самое простое мз командной строки набрать sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

Comment: Ну или, если в пару щелчков запуск утилиты, Программы и обновления.

 на вкладке Дополнительные драйверы ставишь галочку на Nvidia